# Type Boundary "Stickyness" on Wildcards

Tags: scala

I came across this [post](http://www.scala-lang.org/node/8018) on the scala forum.

Here is a recap:

> I just realized that the Scala compiler does not seem to "carry over" type boundaries on wildcards:

```
scala> class Foo { def foo = 42 }
defined class Foo
scala> class Bar[A <: Foo](val a: A)
defined class Bar
scala> def bar(x: Bar[_]) = x.a.foo
:7: error: value foo is not a member of Any
```

> I would expect that the parameter of method bar is still upper-bound by Foo, even though its exact type parameter is unimportant in the method.
>   Is there a specific reason for this behavior?

The discussion then goes into a Spec interpretation dispute :)

### Explanation?

Eventually the poster suggest this explanation:

> However, if the compiler did this for Bar[_], for consistency reasons it would also have to do it for Bar[A]. The latter however would have some strange consequences.
>   def bar[A](x: Bar[A], y: Bob[A])
>   for example would suddenly have to carry an implicit type bound for Bob. If Bob had its own type bound things would be really messy.

Which I don't get because

```
def bar[A](x: Bar[A])
```

alone wouldn't compile since Bar type parameter is bounded.

Anyway I believe the following would make total sense:

```
def bar(x: Bar[_], y : Bob[_])
```

### Workaround

As a workaround they suggest:

```
def bar(x: Bar[_ <: Foo]) = x.a.foo
```

Which beside not being DRY it makes things difficult:

Let's consider a Tree

```
abstract class Tree[T <: Tree[T]] { val subTree : List[T] }
```

Now how would you define functions (defined outside of the Tree class obviously) that are going through the tree recursively:

```
def size( tree : Tree[_] ) = tree.subTree.size + tree.subTree.map(size(_)).sum
```

obviously won't work, since subTree will be turned into a List[Any], so we need a type parameter:

```
def size[T <: Tree[T]]( tree : T ) = ...
```

Even uglier :

```
class OwnATree( val myTree : Tree[_] ){}
```

Should become

```
class OwnATree[T <: Tree[T]]( val myTree : T ){}
```

etc, etc ...

I believe there's something wrong somewhere :)

Comment: You are asking to change the language spec. I don't know what answer could be given? Yes, you need to use either existential types or generic methods. You can hope for Scala 3 with unification of type parameters and type members :)

Comment: @0__: I think there's a clear enough question here (how to write `size`, etc. without a type parameter). I'm also not sure I see how unifying type parameters and type members would help in this case.

Comment: Yes, this question was a bit ambiguous. On one hand I was looking for an explanation other than it's not in the spec - there could be a reason that makes it impossible to implement. On the other hand looking for an alternative to the type parameter - which @TravisBrown answered.

Comment: @Travis : In [this thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/scala-language/PV4q6O1qIh8[1-25]), Martin Odersky sketches the idea of the unification. "The big simplifications are then: (1) Any type can be written without its parameters. [...]" It is unclear whether that means we do get the right bounds (maybe not)... But then also: "Other more narrowly scoped ideas for the type system are to introduce least upper bounds and greatest lower bounds of types as type constructors. This would avoid the explosion of computed lub types that we sometimes see in codebases today." – So I'm hoping...

Answer (score 5):

The simplest way to accomplish what you want with `size` and `OwnATree` is to use an existential type:

```
def size(tree: Tree[T] forSome { type T <: Tree[T] }): Int =
  tree.subTree.size + tree.subTree.map(size(_)).sum
```

And:

```
class OwnATree(val myTree: Tree[T] forSome { type T <: Tree[T] })
```

Your `Tree[_]` versions are actually also using existential types—they're just wrapped up in some syntactic sugar. In other words,

```
def size(tree: Tree[_]): Int = ...
```

Is just syntactic sugar for:

```
def size(tree: Tree[T] forSome { type T }): Int = ...
```

You can't add the constraint you need to the underscore version, but you can to the desugared one.

Comment: Ah yes! I forgot that syntax :) Thanks for pointing it out. Now my code looks better, but I still wonder why we need all that clutter. Shouldn't the compiler be able to "carry over type boundaries" as the original poster said?

Comment: Note that you can also define that as a _type alias_ anywhere, which may be useful if you need to write it dozens of times: `type AnyTree = Tree[T] forSome { type T <: Tree[T] }` and then `def size(tree: AnyTree) ...`

Comment: Nice :) I'm using it like this, maybe there's a better way:
`object Tree { type Any = ... }`
Now i'm running into all sort of problems... [compiler crash](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-6255), [inference bug?](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/scala-user/wT0D4a0aUIg%5B1-25%5D)

Comment: Not to mention that the IDE (Idea in this case) is completely lost :)